# Rails - How do I pass 2 object's ids in a form submission?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form for associating RFID and Device objects.  Upon submission the form passes the id of the rfid automatically.  How can I pass the id of the device which is selected in an options_from_collection_for_select?

Here's the code from the form:

```
<br/>

<div class="well">

<%= form_for(@rfid) do |f| %>
        <table class="table table-bordered">
                <tr>
                    <th>RFID Tag #</th>
                        <td>
                            <%= f.label(:@rfid, @rfid.rfid_tag) %>
                            <%= f.hidden_field :rfid, :value => @rfid %>
                        </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Device Name</th>
                        <td>
                            <%= f.select :device, options_from_collection_for_select(Device.order(:name).where("rfid_tag IS NULL"), "id", "name_or_alternative", @device) %>
                        </td>                               
                </tr>
        </table>
        <%= link_to "Link Device", { :controller => :devices, :action => :assign_rfid_to_device, :device => @device }, :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: It probably is doing it already.  Inspect the params of the request when the form is submitted.  Look at the HTML of the form.  Both of those will give you a grasp of what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a submit button for the form, a link_to isn't enough unless it runs some javascript to submit the form or pass the selection.

```
<%= f.submit 'Link Device' %>
```

Comment: Ok, that will move me in the right direction.  How do I then handle 'Link Device'?  Do I create a method called link_device and put the functionality there?

Comment: I'd advise you to take a step back and consider if you're approaching this from the right side of the association. In your Device model you apparently have a "rfid_tag" field - should that be an rfid_id foreign key? Is this a one to one relationship? Give us some details of your models and table structure and we can give you the most suitable advice.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Matt.  I'm using rfid_tag in the query becuase I'm using pre-existing data where the device objects do not have an rfid_id field.  The data has rfid_tag as the foriegn key for rfid records.  Is my method appropriate?  Otherwise, I got my functionality to work by placing the appropriate commands in the update method of rfids_controller.  Thanks.